# Will I have to redeploy my Applications referencing a WCF if my static IP changes?

Tags: wcf, deployment

I have one of my WPF application, a WCF service and a web service consuming another WCF service deployed on a server with Static IP.
Now, my client is asking me if we can change the server IP.
Will I have to rebuild and redeploy my applications with updated service references with new IP where ever I am using this WCF service or just updating configuration file (web.config/application.exe.config) with updated end point addresses work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know is usually enough to update your `web.config` file as long as the IP will be the only difference.

Comment: Thanks @misleadingTitle, will upvote once I have the required reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

Using dns name, you'll avoid changes when ip changed after dns will be updated.

Comment: Thanks @evgenyl, nice idea! but cant control things at this point in time,btw cant upvote right now :(